# Get value from mysq using php

Tags: php, mysql, email

i'm stuck with the following problem. I want to send a notificationmail when the field "notification" is checked.

So i use this code to see the status of the field "notification":

```
$request = "SELECT user_name, user_email FROM $table WHERE resourceId = $resourceId";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$request);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                                $email=$row["user_email"];
                                                $name=$row["user_name"];
                                                $notification=$row["notification"];
                                                };
```

I'm getting the correct results for $email and $name. 
But the field notification just stays empty. the notification field in de db is a boulean. (also tried with numeric fields, this also does not work)

What am i doing wrong?

kind regards,

Tim

Comment: you did not seleted `notification`

Comment: `$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$request) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));` <= That will show you what errors you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

your SQL query needs to have the `notification` field in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT user_name, user_email, notification FROM $table WHERE resourceId = $resourceId
```

Comment: Thanks, unbelieveble i din't see this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$request = "SELECT user_name, user_email, notification FROM $table WHERE resourceId = $resourceId";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$request);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                                $email=$row["user_email"];
                                                $name=$row["user_name"];
                                                $notification=$row["notification"];
                                                };
```

Comment: Thanks, unbelieveble i din't see this :-)